# Cannot load/open file in R studio using reticulate

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I am using the reticulate package in Rstudio to work with python
I am trying to read/load a pdf file on my desktop into Rstudio using python

The same line of code works when running python from the command prompt, but does not work from Rstudio

````
```{r }
library(reticulate)
```

```{python }
import PyPDF2 as pdf
myfile = open(r'C:\Users\fpaul\Desktop\example.pdf','rb')
```
````

I get the following error:

```
Evaluation error: option error has NULL value.
```

I'm having difficulty understanding the problem, especially since I can seem to do it from the command prompt.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space between the "r" and the file name?

Comment: Possibly the backslash is not rendered properly from R. Try doubling them in file path.

Comment: Neither suggestion works. Would it have anything to do with working directory? I assume not since I am giving the file directory, but is there a way to set working directory in reticulate python? Is it the same as the global working directory for R?